# Close SQLite DB between opening the DB in read-only and read/write mode?

Tags: sqlite

My program currently opens a database in read-only mode.

```
sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, nullptr);
```

Later, I may decide to write to the database, so I will need to promote my connection to read/write. I currently open it again.

```
sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, nullptr);
```

My question is whether I need to call

```
sqlite3_close(db);
```

before opening the database for the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

`sqlite3_open_v2` writes a pointer to a completely new database object to the pointer-to-pointer passed in as the second argument. It doesn't read or do anything with whatever was there before. Failing to call `sqlite3_close` on the old database will cause a resource leak.